# jQuery Datepicker with Swipe Months [Right and Left]

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

As per my requirement, I need a jquery datepicker in which month should be changed by swiping right and left. I tried with customising the jquery datepicker. Please see the below my code:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { alert("Working"); } });
  } );
  $(function() { 
      //Enable swiping...
      $("#ui-datepicker-div").swipe( {
        //Generic swipe handler for all directions
        swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
          if(direction == 'up' || direction == 'right') {
            $(".ui-datepicker-prev").trigger( "click" );
          } else if(direction == 'down' || direction == 'left') {
            $(".ui-datepicker-next").trigger( "click" );
          }
        },
      });
    });
```

But this will work on browser perfectly but when I checked on mobile device date selection is not working.

Please assist me or share any similar jquery datepicker which having swipe functionality.

Thanks in advance.